# "this" as object membership instead of node reference on an event handler?

Tags: javascript, this

```
I={};I.have={};I.have.a={};I.have.a.deep={};I.have.a.deep.deep={};I.have.a.deep.deep.deep={};

I.have.a.deep.deep.deep.niceObj = {

init: function(){
        document.getElementById('xx').addEventListener('click', this.clickHandle)
},
some: function(){},
other: function(){
    // here I can use *this* as I want
    this.some();
},

clickHandle: function(e) {
    // can't use *this* as I want becouse *this* reffers to #xx
    this.some()     // fails!!!

    // here I have a trick, but I realy don't want to reffer 
    // with the full qualified name
    I.have.a.deep.deep.deep.niceObj._clickHandle(e);
},

_clickHandle: function(e) {
    // here again *this* works as I want
    this.some();
}
```

The question is, how can I omit the use of the full qualified object name, inside an embedded event handler, like occurs in clickHandle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to bind the function to the `this` that you want to use.

```
document.getElementById('xx').addEventListener('click', this.clickHandle.bind(this));
```

`this` in an object function refers to the caller of the function, so when your object calls the function, as in `niceObj.init()`, `this` would be `niceObj`. The event listener calls the function with the event target as `this`.

So you bind that event listener function to the object instead, which should be `this` if `niceObj` was the caller of `init`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind